# Learning by listening versus learning by reading

Tags: developmental-psychology, educational-psychology

I would like to know whether there is a study in psychology which compares the effectiveness of learning by reading versus learning by listening.

I would assume learning by reading is better because you can fixate on certain words at the intervals you want,  skip back and forth, things that are not possible with audio.

But with audio one could listen to different sources taking simultaneously, even if of course one could follow different books at the same time.

Thanks.